Find sum of power series
The problem is to find the sum of the power series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$$
My solution:
First to find where the sum exists (for which x):
Using D'Alembert's criterion for finding the radius:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)}, R = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| = 1 \implies x \in (-1, 1)$$
Now checking the endpoints of the interval $1$ and $-1$:
$$x=1: \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$$
$$x=-1: \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$$

(because 2n+1 is odd $\forall n$, so it's always negative and its the
negative of the case $x=1$)

And now checking using Raabe-Duhamel convergence test we can see that both are convergent, since when $x=-1$ the sum is equal to the negative of the sum when $x=1$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(\frac{(2n+3)(n+2)}{(2n+1)(n+1)}-1) = 2 > 1 \implies convergent \implies x \in [-1, 1]$$
Now how can I find the sum of the series? I'm familiar with the geometric series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ax^n = \frac{a}{1-x}$$
I also have seen when the power of x is different than n like in this case $2n+1$ to use some sort of mapping, but I'm not sure whether to use it or not and how exactly to make it work:
Method 1 (renaming the object):
$$b_m = \left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
0,& m = 2n\\
a_n,& m = 2n + 1
\end{array}\right.$$
Method 2 (substitution):
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{2n+1}\tag{2}=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(x^{2})^n, t = x^2 \implies t^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}t^n$$
Partial fraction decomposition (PFD):
$$\frac{1}{(2n+1)(n+1)}=\frac{2}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Hint: you know the second derivative of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}$.

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}
$$
We have x$\in(-1,1)$ then
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{n+1}=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n}=-\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x^2}$$
therfore:
$$f(x)=\int -\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x^2} dx=\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x} +2\int \frac{1}{1-x^2}dx=\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x} +\ln\left({\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\right)+c$$
And we have : $f(0)=0\implies c=0$

It's not obvious that $c=0$ because the first term of your sum is indeterminate at $x=0$.  At a minimum, you should show $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln (1-x^2)}{x^2}=0$.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln (1-x^2)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}  \dfrac{-2x}{1-x^2}=0
$

HINT: The term $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(n+1)}$ looks like an antiderivative of the term $\frac{x^{2n}}{n+1}$. This suggests that maybe $x^2$ has been substituted into a series with terms like $\frac{x^n}{n}$, and possibly multiplied or divided by $x$. Fiddle with that series to find the function you want. Do you recognize $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ ?

Based on a similar procedure, you can start first by doing a partial fraction decomposition

Yes, I also recognize that one $= -ln(1-x)$, since the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}=-ln(1-x)$. Alright thanks for the hint I'll try to work on this
